# Trying to change the value of an attribute

Tags: javascript

```
 var btnl=document.getElementById("btnl");
 var btns=document.getElementById("btns");
 var log=document.querySelector("log");
 var sub=document.querySelector("sub");
 var hide=document.querySelector("hide");
//when the user clicks the button the class changes
 btnl.addEventListener('click', function(){
    log.setAttribute("class","olog");
 });

 btns.addEventListener('click', function(){
 sub.setAttribute("class","osub");
 });
```

Whenever I run the page the nothing happens. Right now I've no clue where I made my mistake.

Comment: Make sure to check the browser's console for errors.

Comment: It would be neat if you could include all of the side effects you expected as a result of clicking that button.  e.g. Which element is being clicked?  What type of element is it?  What styles are assigned to that the classes `olog` and `osub` and do they differ from the default styles?  All of these clues would be helpful to answerers.  Feel free to edit your question to include them.

Comment: It would be better to provide HTML snippet too, because it is possible you use wrong selectors.

Comment: do you have a `<log>`, `<sub>` and `<hide>` element?

Comment: `Whenever I run the page the nothing happens` - nothing will happen, unless you click **the** element with `id="btns"` or **the** element with `id="btnl"`